# rmongodb $in query issues

Tags: r, rmongodb

I have really enjoyed working with rmongodb and have figured out how to do a lot of different things/combination of queries but this one still stumps me. I am trying to get all of the documents that have the symbol: field equal to an element of a vector (named symbols in r).

Query that works on my MongoDB DB that I am trying to replicate in r

```
{symbol: {"$in": ["SYMBOLA","SYMBOLB","SYMBOLC","SYMBOLD","SYMBOLE"]} }
```

In r...

```
symbols <- list("SYMBOLA","SYMBOLB","SYMBOLC","SYMBOLD","SYMBOLE")
mongo.find.all(mongo, namespace, query = list(symbol = list('$in' = symbols)))
```

Doesnt seem to work (since I am not used to the syntax I tried all sorts of combinations without luck. Feel like I am missing something here.

Any help on how I can query specific documents based on a symbols vector in R would be a huge help.

EDIT:
Here is the print of the BSON:

```
symbol : 3   
        $in : 4      
            0 : 2    SYMBOLA
            1 : 2    SYMBOLB
            2 : 2    SYMBOLC
            3 : 2    SYMBOLD
            4 : 2    SYMBOLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine on my machine

```
symbols <- list("SYMBOLA","SYMBOLB","SYMBOLC","SYMBOLD","SYMBOLE")
mongo <- mongo.create()
for (ch in symbols) 
  mongo.insert(mongo, 'test.test', list(symbol = ch))
# insert one more symbol that don't match our condition
mongo.insert(mongo, 'test.test', list(symbol = 'incorrect_symbol'))

res <- mongo.find.all(mongo, 'test.test', query = list(symbol = list('$in' = symbols)))
length(res)
#> 5
```

Comment: That is definitely part of it, now at least I have symbols as a list, however the query still doesnt work. I have tried a couple of different variations of the syntax and also tried building up using... mongo.bson.from.list(lst=list(symbol=list("$in"=symbols)))

Comment: that is strange, should work. Do you use latest rmongodb version? Also could you please check bson: `print(mongo.bson.from.list(lst=list(symbol=list("$in"=symbols))) )`

Comment: I added the print in the main post, thank you for your help in this. Also using rmongodb_1.8.0

Comment: Hmm very strange, I agree, I can get your example to work but then cant get it to work on my database. The ns parameter is correct because I can retrieve all documents if I dont include a query... Ill keep trying things on my end.

Comment: I just realized that mongo.find.all seems to only be querying the first 2600 documents in my DB, when there are over 16,000. That would explain why it cannot find the symbols at the end, the syntax is probably correct. Any ideas why its not searching further?

Comment: Finally figured out the limitation on my end, so sorry for dragging you through that. Thank you for your patience and for helping me get that query right. $in is so powerful, allowing so much to work. Thanks again for such an incredible package, switching all sorts of stuff over to mongodb and loving it.